# Are these the symbols files?

Tags: hockeyapp

I am developing windows store apps. I know that I should upload symbol files to hockey dashboard for better diagnosing of bugs for my app. The symbol files are in my Microsoft's developer dashboard's app's current package section.

My doubt is, Visual studio creates files named "MyApp_1.1.3.0_x86.appxsym" and "MyApp_1.1.3.0_x64.appxsym" files in the AppPackages folder while creating app packages. I want to know are these the symbol files, that I can upload to my hockey dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. These are the symbol files.

You should upload all these symbols so that you could get your crashes desymboled correctly on these different platforms, zip the three symbols in folder and upload it to the corresponding version, for the details of the process please refer this kb: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application. (Ref:Hockeyapp support)

The *.appxsym files contain the public symbols from your app. They are created from the *.pdb files.